# Blurry/Pixelated fonts after changing screen's scaling size to 125% on ubuntu wayland

Tags: display, fonts, display-resolution, wayland

I wanted to play wine games that only worked in Wayland so I started a new session and when I set the resolution to 125% I ended up with some completely disgusting text fonts that didn't look like nothing at all if you will allow me. If there is anyone who could help me with my problem I sincerely thank him.

NOTE: I would not accept any responses like "Open a normal session", "Set your resolution to 100%" and etc.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you have blurry (or pixelated) fonts is because Ubuntu is scaling the font size without changing the font size (like what you do in Word). It other words it is taking a SVG image, rasterizing it, and instead rescaling **from** the font's SVG image which would yield a good quality,  it just scaled up the rasterized font version (created by Ubuntu, perhaps on startup?). And the rasterized font goes pixel to pixel on the screen when you are on 100%, so therefore it would look a litte blocky on 125%.

There is no fix. They mentioned [here](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/06/enable-fractional-scaling-ubuntu-19-04#:%7E:text=As%20mentioned%20the%20default%20display,like%20125%25%20or%20150%25.&text=How%3F&text=Once%20set%2C%20you%20can%20open,including%20125%25%20and%20150%25.) that the feature is experimental, so they probably have not gotten to the problem of scaling rasterized font letters on your machine set.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by setting the scale to 100% and selecting "Large text" in the Accessibility settings.